# How to align div above and below?

Tags: html, css

Below are two div's that have another two div's below it. I would like to layer them so that they are perfectly aligned below.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;  /* grow */
  border: 1px dashed #f0f;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 250px; /* do not grow, do not shrink, start at 250px */
  border: 1px dashed #00f;
}

.leftTop {
  position: absolute;
  /* what to do here? */
}
  
.rightTop {
  position: absolute;
  /* what to do here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right 250px</div>
  <div class="leftTop">Left Top Layer</div>
  <div class="rightTop">Right Top Layer</div>
</div>
```

I do not get the same effect for the top layer when I duplicate the left and right for the top.

Comment: What do you mean with "perfectly aligned"? Do the divs have to be in that order? Do you need to have the "position: absolute" defined?

Comment: that the borders of the div are aligned on top of each other. The order of the div's matter. Position isn't absolutely necessary but I put it there because that's what I thought would allow me to layer the div underneath it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for floats (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp is a decent starting place)

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/31rqsn93/

Comment: not quite, the words inside I don't care so much about it's the outer border that has to line up even when you shrink the viewport. https://jsfiddle.net/31rqsn93/9/

Comment: Could you give any kind of image of what you want exactly?

Comment: @Alison it seems as if you lack understanding on how position property works in css. Adding to that, your question is not clear. Either make your question clearer or learn what position property does 
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @divine Thank you for the suggestion. I'll be reading more on position property to improve the way I form my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding `relative` positioned wrappers that contain the top and bottom `div`s and positioning the `top` layers `absolute` inside the wrappers.

So you would have:

```
box
  left
    bottom
    top
  right
    bottom
    top
```

Here is a snippet:

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    flex: 1;
}

.right {
    flex: 0 0 250px;
}

.bottom {
    height: 100%;
}
  
.top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/* These are just for illustration purposes */

.left, .right {
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.top, .bottom {
    border: 3px dashed;
}

.bottom {
    border-color: red;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
  
.top {
    border-color: blue;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="bottom">
            Left<br>top<br>layer<br><br>These still align
        </div>

        <div class="top">
            Left<br>bottom<br>layer
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="bottom">
            Right<br>top<br>layer
        </div>

        <div class="top">
            Right<br>bottom<br>layer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks vkopio, I figured I had to separate it into another div. I had a different solution that seemed to kinda work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/31rqsn93/16/ but I like your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting width:100% for the leftTop div?

```
.leftTop {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width:100%;
}
```

**Code link:** https://jsfiddle.net/31rqsn93/12/